# How do I make RNG give same results for the same input?

Tags: godot, gdscript

What I need to do:

1. Take a string as input
2. Change characters inside of it randomly
3. Return changed string

I can do all 3 steps, no problem. BUT, I need the changed characters in the string to be the same every time I input this particular string. So, for example:

"Hello" should always become "32864"

But as it is now, I always get different results even when using the same seed.
As it is now, I define the new RNG, set the seed, call the function that changes the characters. All in ready().

```
var test_rand = RandomNumberGenerator.new()
test_rand.seed = hash("Simple key")
print(function("Hello", other parameters, test_rand)
print(function("Hello", other parameters, test_rand)
print(function("Hello", other parameters, test_rand)
```

All 3 results are different.
If you are wondering, no, there are no additional unique RNGs inside the function (text = "Hello"):

```
var return_string = text
var changed_indexes = []
var index
for i in len(text):
    while true:
        index = test_rand.randi_range(0, len(text)-1)
        if index not in changed_indexes:
            changed_indexes.append(index)
            break
    return_string[index] = alphabet[test_rand.randi() % alphabet.size()]
return return_string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Random Number Generator

When you seed the random number generator, that seed will define the *sequence* of results you will get.

That *sequence* will eventually repeat, after you take a large number of randomic values.

---

Without going into the mathematics behind it, the idea is that the random number generator holds some internal state, and every time you generate a number with it, it also updates the internal state. By [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), the internal state will eventually repeat, and thus the whole *sequence* will repeat.

And... When you seed the random number generator, you are setting the internal state.

---

Thus, if you seed your random number generator, and then run your function with it without seeding it again, every time the function run will get a different result (until eventually it repeats), because it is just further down the *sequence*.

Since you want it to repeat right away, what you would have to do is to seed it again each time. That is, you want to restart the *sequence*.

---

### HMAC

I'm not convinced that a random number generator is the tool you want.

It seems you want to:

- Have the same result from the same input.
- Have some key involved in the process.
- Have it impossible to recover the input from the output.

That sounds like an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) to me.

---

Godot actually offers an HMAC solution under the `Crypto` class (Crypto as in Cryptography, not as in NFT).

Example:

*Godot 3*

```
var key := "Simple key"
var data := "Hello"

var crypto := Crypto.new()
var digest = crypto.hmac_digest(
    HashingContext.HASH_SHA1,
    key.to_utf8(),
    data.to_utf8()
)
prints(digest)
```

*Godot 4*

```
var key := "Simple key"
var data := "Hello"

var crypto := Crypto.new()
var digest = crypto.hmac_digest(
    HashingContext.HASH_SHA1,
    key.to_utf8_buffer(),
    data.to_utf8_buffer()
)
prints(digest)
```

Output:

```
[87, 94, 68, 177, 213, 141, 100, 111, 144, 212, 87, 173, 176, 199, 210, 133, 50, 194, 134, 7]
```

Or use `prints(digest.hex_encode())`:

```
575e44b1d58d646f90d457adb0c7d28532c28607
```

*You might also be interested in `get_string_from_ascii`.*

Above I demonstrated `HASH_SHA1`, assuming this is not a security concern, that should be fine. You might even further modify it or truncate it to the length you need. Otherwise know that `HASH_SHA256` is also supported, and it is recommended cryptographically secure solution, and don't mess with it.

Comment: Wow and thank you for the explanations) The re-seeding works as I wanted it to :D Initially, I assumed that whenever you make a call to the Generator it will use the default (set) seed automatically. HMAC is kinda the thing I'm going for, but it's more complex and not fit for a simple game)